# Issues with creating custom personalization rule

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8

Below is my code for custom personalization rule:

```
using MyDll.Custom_Classes.Analytics.Facets;
using Sitecore.Analytics;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Rules;
using Sitecore.Rules.Conditions;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyDll.Custom_Classes.Personalization_Rules
{
    public class AnonymousUserInterestsCondition<T> : StringOperatorCondition<T> where T : RuleContext
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }

        protected override bool Execute(T ruleContext)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(ruleContext, "ruleContext");
            Assert.IsNotNull(Tracker.Current, "Tracker.Current is not initialized");
            Assert.IsNotNull(Tracker.Current.Session, "Tracker.Current.Session is not initialized");
            Assert.IsNotNull(Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction, "Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction is not initialized");

            var currentAnonymousUserInterest = string.Empty;
            if (Tracker.Current.Contact != null)
            {
                var interestsFacet = Tracker.Current.Contact.GetFacet<IInterestFacet>(InterestFacet._FACET_NAME);
                if (!interestsFacet.Interests.Any())
                {
                    currentAnonymousUserInterest = interestsFacet.Interests[0].InterestedIn;
                }
            }

            return Compare(currentAnonymousUserInterest, Value);
        }
    }
}
```

I am referencing it in sitecore type field as below:

MyDll.Custom_Classes.Personalization_Rules.AnonymousUserInterestsCondition,MyDll

Please refer screen shot below:

[image: Personalization Rule - Sitecore error for Type field]

Sitecore displays error for Type field and the error message is "The field Type contains reference for non-existing type MyDll.Custom_Classes.Personalization_Rules.AnonymousUserInterestsCondition,MyDll"

Am I doing anything wrong or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Double check the spelling is 100% correct. Also make sure you have deployed the DLL to the bin folder of your website.

Comment: @jammykam I verified it and its 100% correct, even the dll has been deployed to website bin.

Comment: This is now fixed. I renamed namespace without having '_' in it and updated type in sitecore. It worked